Convert Tensorflow model to custom hardware
What are the options to convert a tensorflow model to a custom hardware without hacking mlir or any other complex tasks like creating own delegate. These are my options (any others?):

I am thinking converting to tensorflowlite model but i have no idea how to limit tflite base ops (tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8). Any suggestions? I am looking for a solution that doesn't require changing the original Keras/TF model.

How about converting to another flow (PyTorch, ONNX, etc.). I don't have any experience on any of these tools. A reference to an easy intro would be appreciated.


Thanks
Tried converting to TFLite which includes a number of operations (e.g. Sigmoid/Logistic) which is supported on my custom hardware.
